# Chrome Ignoring Font Smoothing Antialiased

Tags: css

I've spent the last few hours tearing my hair out on a CSS bug I can't figure out. I frequently use:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

To improve the appearance of typography. [On my own website](http://www.matthallock.com), this suddenly seems to no longer be working. It appears as if this style is getting ignored within the same body of text.

[Weight changing between paragraphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Hoxz.png)

Highlighting seems to change the appearance on the line of the text as well.

I've tried various implementations of font-smoothing. Globally (from the body), to specific divs, and even to specific fonts. I can't nail down the reason this is happening. It doesn't seem to be an issue in Firefox or Safari. Is this possibly an issue with Chrome others are having?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page you screenshotted (not a word, I know)?

Comment: Okay, I've been throughout your site, didn't locate the exact portion of text you screenshotted but I have not been able to reproduce the issue in Chrome 54. Maybe your Chrome version has a bug? Maybe it's a platform-specific thing?

Comment: You can visit the site at http://www.matthallock.com it's pretty prevalent on the about page text since that's a longer body of text. I am using Version 54.0.2840.71 (64-bit) on OS X.

Comment: Yeah, I don't need the link to your website again, I said I visited your site and couldn't reproduce the problem. Hardware-acceleration blurs fonts significantly when animations take place, mucking up font rendering. You can try applying font smoothing properties when the transitions/animations end, but it's not guaranteed to work. You could also try applying `-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased`, which Chrome supports and might make things a bit better.

Comment: Hmm… Subpixel-antialiasing produces a different kind of effect.To your point about animations, I tried disabling all JS and webkit animations and the effect still persists. I downgraded to 53.0.2785.116 and the problem resolves itself. Possible that this is a bug from the 10/21 update of Chrome, but curious you don't seem to be seeing it. I'm also seeing the issue on a work laptop.

Comment: Adding two other pieces of context I've found. First, the problem goes away if the browser is resized at all. Second, it appears that the problem doesn't appear in divs that are loaded below the browser fold.